# Spark Structured Streaming: Joining streams that span years

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

My team and I are fairly new to spark structured streaming and have struggled to understand how to apply spark streaming to our problem space. All of the data at my company are moving to Kafka and I need to move to that platform as well (from RabbitMQ). The queues from RabbitMQ will now be moved to topics in Kafka. I need to aggregate multiple topics together for reporting purposes and then dump them to a data store (currently Postgres). The report data goes back a 10+ years and there is always new, incoming data.

One of the large issues we've failed to understand is this:

**How does one join real time data with historical records spanning many years?**

Our attempts at the problem:

**Attempt 1:**

Our initial approach was to do a stream to stream join of our data. One of our concerns with that idea was that since we deal in historical records, and we aren't guaranteed that they would arrive in order (some records could arrive months later), and we haven't been confident that all of the data would be joined correctly. We would also need to do some sort of watermarking on the join, but our watermark would essentially be for all time. Holding all of that data in memory and watermarking for a year+ doesn't seem to be realistic or make sense, so we put that idea on pause. We also toyed with the idea of doing broadcast joins with the smaller topic, but the data from both sides is sizable and is constantly changing (my understanding of a broadcast join is the data you broadcast is static and doesn't change... please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Attempt 2:**

We landed on the idea of joining a stream to a store, in our case, a Postgres database (we call a cache) and then publish to our new topic. We have to regularly change the data in the cache, which then needs to be propagated to the output topic. Our current solution requires us to restart the job from the beginning and reprocess in order to publish corrections. Restarting the job from the beginning is not ideal, and is becoming a burden.

One note I should make is that both topics that we are trying to join need to initiate the join with the other.

One final idea that we have had, and think it might work, is this:

**Proposed attempt 3:**

Job `A` produce a cache.

Job `B` would also produce a cache.

Job `A` would look at job `B`'s cache and see if there are any records to join on as data streams into job `A`.

Job `B` would look at job `A`'s cache and see if there are any records to join on as data streams into job `B`.

Both `A` and `B` will publish to the same topic `T`. The output of `T` would be stored in a Postgres database `D` (essentially another cache).

Job `C` would publish data corrections by joining with `D` and publishing the corrections to `T`.

This seems to be the surest way to go about joining historical data.

My questions:

What design patterns should we follow to build aggregated, historical records from multiple Kafka topics? e.g., user `a` was doing `xyz` at a point in time and they were associated with organization `b`

Should we be joining a stream with a static data source (a postgres table in our case)?